# Jquery This is Null When Used in Ajax Generated Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a jquery function with the following structure

```
function StartSong(e, sender) { }
```

I call it with the following html

```
<h4 onclick="StartSong(event, this)"> <a class="button small d3 playButton" href="javascript: var c=1;">
```

When the page is loaded some of the songs are shown, and when clicked to play the sender object in the function contains this data, which is expected

```
({jQuery18307744602853717308:8, sizcache04790260167065139:"6 18 0", sizset:false})
```

Although when I load more songs through ajax and append the html to the page (the same html as above) and the function is called through a click the sender variable in the function is null.

Does anyone see any reason for this?

Comment: I'm only guessing here but I think it's got something to do with the element being a `h4`. Can you try changing it to a div and see if it works?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, change `onclick="StartSong(event, this)"` to `onclick="StartSong(event)"` and `function StartSong(e, sender)` to `function StartSong(e)` and then use `e.target` instead of `sender`. Below is the snippet.

Your HTML,

```
<h4 onclick="StartSong(event)"> 
<a class="button small d3 playButton" href="javascript: var c=1;">
```

And your js,

```
function StartSong(e) { 
    var sender = e.target; //now use sender as you have been using.
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this made no difference.